# Creating a generic Array2D wrapper class

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, data-structures

For the sake of more easily switching between different data structures I'd like to create a generic wrapper class for a 2D array...

```
public sealed class Array2D<T>
{
    private T<,> _fields;

    public Array2D()
    {
    }
}
```

`private T<,> _fields;` is giving me the error:

> The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with type arguments

I'm having a hard time understanding C# generics in this case. How would I be able to solve this?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx before you attempt to build your own? And as @Agalo suggested you need to specify the types for the run time to understand. Or may be you can try private List<T> _fields; If you are actually looking for two dim array, try List<List<SomeType>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<,>` is for referencing unbound generic types. What you are looking for is `[,]`:

```
public sealed class Array2D<T>
{
    private T[,] _fields;

    public Array2D()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a dumb mistake of mine. Of course arrays are defined with square braces!

Answer (score 1):

to declare array you need to use `[]` so it should be

```
T[,] array;
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Multidimensional Arrays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx) is like this:

```
private T[,] _fields;
```

So you should:

```
public sealed class Array2D<T>
{
     private T[,] _fields;

     //Or as property
     public T[,] Fields
     {
         get { return _fields; }
         set { _fields = value; }
     }

     public Array2D()
     {

     }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Array2D<int> arr = new Array2D<int> {Fields = new[,] {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `List<List<SomeType>>` for two dim array. May be `List<List<T>>` in your case. This would be generic as well. And add the using statements `using System.Linq;` `using System.Linq.Expressions;` You can get very rich functionality as well.